# How to break an Angular2 app when using server side template inheritance

Tags: angular

In Angular2, everything starts at an application level component and everything else is a part of its tree. If I am using ExpressJS on the server side to render m my home page the first time, how do I go about setting up my layout and my index views on the server? Does my angular app live in my index view and my layout which potentially could be inherited by other pages be non-angular code? I am guessing my layout file cannot have something to this effect:

```
<body>
  <app>Loading...</app>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Or is my content supposed to go inside my `app` component? Like so:

```
<body>
  <app>
     Loading...
     {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </app>
</body>
```

Comment: I assume second approach is better. And non-angular stuff won't have problem being child of some angular html node. so...

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is typically your HTML boiler-plate, e.g. `html`, `head`, google analytics tracking code, footer, header, perhaps menu. If you add your angular app here then you can't really re-use this layout.

I'd expect your index page (which is an HTML fragment that is included into the layout), to be nothing more than an instance of your angular top-level component, together with associated script tags.

Comment: Not always. The layout could include boilerplate code like logged in user, the navigation and so on powered by Angular.